# Добавить новое поле к сущности перед отдачей ответа по REST

Tags: java, архитектура, dto

Мне нужно получить из БД объект и отправить его по REST, предварительно добавив к нему несколько новых полей. Как это лучше сделать? Я вижу несколько вариантов:

1. Создать и заполнить DTO прямо в слое сервиса, вернуть DTO контроллеру.
2. Создать некий POJO объект, вернуть его контроллеру, в контроллере сконвертировать POJO в DTO.
3. Создать новый вариант сущности, работать с ним в слое сервиса/репозиториях, с контроллере сконвертировать в DTO

Имею не слишком много опыта в проектировании архитектуры, не знаю как сделать правильно и по всем канонам. Буду благодарен за советы.

Comment: Ответ сильно зависит от того, что это за поле и что за сущность.

Comment: Ну если уже есть такая сущность, то нужно в классе этой сущности добавить эти поля и усе по сути. 
И естественно как то их инициализировать.

Comment: Если упростить задачу, мне нужно взять из базы объект и перед отдачей на фронт нужно прилепить к объекту сообщение о том, был ли объект уже создан раньше, или он был создан в момент обращения.

Добавлять поле в сущность не хотелось бы, т.к. это только одна задача, для которой используется эта сущность.

Comment: Тогда создать класс в котором будет то что вам нужно и ссылка на сущность из базы.

Comment: Это будет Model?) А можно в одном проекте делать и Model, и Entity?